# Proving that $\sin x$ and $\sin 2x$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove that $\sin x$ and $\sin 2x$ are linearly independent. So I need to show that $a\sin x + b\sin 2x = 0$ only if $a=b=0$.

Though I am not entirely understanding why they are linearly independent. This equation is satisfied if $x=0$ regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$. How then can I show that they are linearly independent?

Comment: Try evaluating at a convenient values of $x$ to simplify the equation. For what value of $x$, for example, does $\sin 2 x$ vanish but not $\sin 2 x$?

Comment: It's not that a sin x + b sin 2x = 0 only if... (If x = $\pi$/3 then sin x - sin 2x = 0).  It's a matter of showing sin x + b sin 2x = 0 *for all possible values of x* only if...

Comment: A linear dependence relation between the **functions** $\sin x$ and $\sin 2x$ would require a pair of real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\sin x + b\sin 2x = 0$ for **every** x. Travis's comment above then shows the easiest way to go.

Comment: Something like considering this within the vector space $C^\infty (\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: Um... I don't know if this is legit: If so, then  a sin 90 + b sin 180 = a = 0. So a sin 45 + b sin 90 = 0 sin 45 + b = b = 0 so b = 0.  Is that acceptable?  It seems kind of .... simple.

Comment: My hint above should read "...does $\sin 2x$ vanish but not $\sin x$" (NB the coefficient in the latter is just $1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
the $0$ in
$$
a\sin x +b\sin 2x=0 
$$
is the **zero function** ( the neutral element for the sum in the space of functions), not the real number $0$.

Comment: THIS! That was something that confused me alot back in my college year.

Answer (score 1):

First, the definition of linear independence says that it's equal to $0$ if and only if the coefficients $a = b = 0$, since that will always be satisfied.

Now recall that $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$. Thus,

$$a \sin x + b \sin 2x = a \sin x + 2b \sin x \cos x = (a+ 2b \cos x) \sin x $$

Now this is $0$ if and only if $\sin x = 0$ or $a + 2b \cos x = 0$. $\sin x \ne 0$ as functions and the latter is equivalent to $a = b = 0$, since $\cos x$ is not a constant function.